# GeneralException when try to insert content control in the table row

Tags: office-js

Every time when i try to insert ContentControl in the table row I got GeneralException.
Example code:

```
   Word.run(async (context) => {
       let table: Word.Table = context.document.getSelection().parentTable;
       table.load("rowCount, rows/items/cells/items/body");
       await context.sync();

       let rows: Word.TableRowCollection = table.rows;

       for (let i: number = 0; i < rows.items.length; i++) {
           let range: Word.Range = null;
           for (let j: number = 0; j < rows.items[i].cells.items.length; j++){
               if (range == null) {
                   range = rows.items[i].cells.items[j].body.getRange();
               } else {
                   range = range.expandTo(rows.items[i].cells.items[j].body.getRange());
               }
           }
           range.insertContentControl();
       }
       return context.sync();
   }).catch((error) => {
       this.errorEmitter.emit(error);
   });
```

This error I got only in word online. In desktop word it works perfect.
What I am doing wrong?
[tableExample.docx](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/files/1152706/tableExample.docx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be correct for this case.
However, table cell and table row content control is not supported by word online now. That's why you get this exception.